# Is it possible to manage the multiple countries with single store?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to setup a single store to manage the multiple countries. In this case, EAV (Price, shopping cart rules, reports, language etc.) value can be set on the Country based not on the store view based (As of Magento).

Thank you so much for your thoughts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to setup multiple countries in single store.In order to achieve this you will have to write custom extension or use existing extensions.

checkout below extension provides similar functionality to restrict product display for certain country based on users `GEO Location`

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/country-specific-products.html

Checkout this [Advanced Pricing](https://merchantprotocol.com/#.UdQJDj6gkTc) extension too.

**OR**

You can use [GEO-IP Language & Currency Switcher](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/geo-ip-language-currency-switcher.html)